# Returning value of None object

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, methods, avl-tree

I have got adding method in my AVL tree implementation.

```
class Node:    
    def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None, height = -1):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.height = height
    def addNode(self, data):
        if self.data > data:
            '''Adding to left subtree'''
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.addNode(data)
                if ( abs(self.right.height - self.left.height) == 2):
                    ''' Then we need to balance a subtree''' 
                    print("Rebalancing after inserting", data)
                    if (data < self.left.data):
                        self.rotateLeft()
                    else:
                        self.doubleRotateLeft()

        elif self.data < data:
            '''Adding to right subtree'''
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.addNode(data)
                if ( abs(self.right.height - self.left.height) == 2):
                    ''' Then we need to balance a subtree'''
                    print("Rebalancing after inserting", data)
                    if (data < self.right.data):
                        self.rotateRight()
                    else:
                        self.doubleRotateRight()
```

But when I try to do

```
self.right.height
```

and self hasn't got right object then it will not return height, even default value is -1. How can I fix it? I am trying to make as less duplicated code in this method as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `self.right` is set to `None` you can't use `self.right.height`, no. Don't use `None` if that expression must work. Use a sentinel that defines that attribute, instead.

A sentinel can be just a custom class that has no value and no child nodes. You can make that a singleton just like `None`:

```
class Sentinel(object):
    value = left = right = None
    height = -1

sentinel = Sentinel()

class Node:    
    def __init__(self, data, left=sentinel, right=sentinel, height=-1):
        # ...
```

then test for `is sentinel` instead of `is None` in your code. By using `sentinel` as the default value for the `left` and `right` keyword arguments, `self.left.height` and `self.right.height` will always work (provided `self` is an instance of `Node`).

Don't forget to increment `height` each time you create a new node though.

You can simplify your `addNone()` method a little by using local references:

```
def addNode(self, data):
    if self.data == data: return
    left = self.data > data
    testnode = self.left if left else self.right
    if testnode is sentinel:
        node = Node(data)
        setattr(self, 'left' if left else 'right', node)
    else:
        testnode.addNode(data)
        if abs(self.right.height - self.left.height) == 2:
            if data < testnode.data:
                rotation = self.rotateLeft if left else self.rotateRight
            else:
                rotation = self.doubleRotateLeft if left else self.doubleRotateRight
            rotation()
```

Comment: Thanks. And could you hint me how to avoid duplicating a code?

Comment: You mean the code for both `self.left` and `self.right`? Why not create a new node in a new variable `node`, assign it to either `left` or `right`, then apply all those changes to that one `node` reference?

Comment: yes I meant that the same algorithm is for right and left subtree. Thanks, your solution is great!

Comment: I've reduced it to 13 lines; you could use a dispatch table for the rotations (using a tuple of `(bool, bool)` values for `left` and `data < testnode.data` as keys) to reduce that further.

Comment: Ok and how about incrementing height you mentioned before? Isn't this alghoritm okay?

Comment: In an AVL tree, the height of a given node is the maximum height of it's children plus one. So each time you add a node, you need to propagate the height back up. Perhaps `addNode()` could return the new height for that child, etc.? You'll need to think about this.

Comment: but your adding method is wrong because if you changed a way of checking if it should be left or right then it allows to add duplicated nodes

Comment: @Mateusz: then add `if self.data == data: return` to the method.

Comment: ok, just one more question, is using a "left" or "isLeft" boolean variable correct with oop rules? I thought that passing booleans that tell if we are using left or right subtree is not correct. In java I was just using different comparators for right and left subtree

Comment: It is a local variable in the function. It greatly simplifies the code, avoiding excessive repetition. There is no OOP here, this is all just procedural code within one function, it is not as if this can be delegated to different types.